# LINQ returns 0 results if using nullable int variable, accurate results if using "null"

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a table called "test", which only has 1 column, "NullableInt" (nullable int type)

The records are: 1, 2, null

```
int? nullableInt = null;
var t = db.tests.Where(x => x.NullableInt == null).ToList(); // returns 1 record
var t2 = db.tests.Where(x => x.NullableInt == nullableInt).ToList(); // returns 0 records
```

For some reason, t2 returns 0 records, even tho it's using "nullableInt" variable, which has a value of null, just like t, which is comparing against "null"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries could be built in this way:

```
var q = db.tests;
if(nullableInt.HasValue)
{
   q = q.Where(x => x.NullableInt == nullableInt.Value);
}
else
{
   q = q.Where(x => x.NullableInt == null);
}
var t2 = q.ToList();
```

Comment: See my answer below, this is fixed in EF6 and you can opt in to a fix in EF5.

Answer (score 6):

Yep - it's a bug in LINQ-to-SQL / Entity Framework.  `IS NULL` queries will only be generated if you hardcode null into the query, instead of a variable that happens to currently be null.

The second query will generate

```
SELECT .......
WHERE NullableInt == @someParam
WHERE @someParam is null.
```

Where the first will generate the appropriate `IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.

If you're using LINQ-to-SQL, you can log your queries to Console.Out to see for yourself, and if you're using EF, then ToTraceString() should show you the same info (or SQL Server profiler)

Comment: Actually I don't think it's a bug because in the second expression `nullableInt` is not `null` even you assign its value with `nullableInt = null`(since it's a struct,whose value can't be null). Thus the framework treats it like other structs(such as an int).

Comment: @Danny, that's splitting hairs. The bug could be in the specification, even if the code does exactly what the specification says it should do. In other words, the bug here might not be that the code happens to do something wrong, but that someone didn't consider this scenario.

Comment: Splitting hairs indeed.  There's no justifiable reason why the EF parser should generate the second query to be anything other than IS NULL.  And this has been logged as a bug with MS (with a very high vote count) though I don't have that link at hand.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

If you use DbContext in EF6 this is fixed.

If you're using EF5 (or ObjectContext in EF6) you need to set ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior to true. To do that on DbContext use this:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true;
```

.

**More details**

The root cause of this issue is a difference in how the database compares null values and how C# compares null values. Because you write your query in C# you want to use the semantics of C#.

In EF5 we introduced ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior, which allowed you to opt in to using C# semantics instead of database semantics. The default is false (so that existing queries don't magically start returning different results when you upgrade to EF5). But you can set it to true and both your queries will return rows.

If you are using DbContext in EF5 you need to drop down to the ObjectContext to set it:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true;
```

If you are using EF6, then it's already set to true on DbContext so you are good to go. We decided this causes so much confusion it was worth taking the potential impact on existing queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that will always work, albeit with a small caveat:

```
int? nullableInt = null;
var t2 = db.tests.Where(x => object.Equals(x.NullableInt, nullableInt)).ToList();
```

When the value is null you will get the proper `IS NULL` query, however when its not null you will get something like:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ([t0].[NullableInt] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t0].[NullableInt] = @p0)
```

Obviously it has a condition extra (the source of which is kind of puzzling). That being said, SQL Server's query optimizer should detect that, since @p0 is a non-null value, the first condition is a superset and will cut the where clause.

Comment: That may work in LINQ-to-SQL (I haven't tested it) but it definitely does *not* work in EF4.  It still generates the same old = @param where @param is set to null

Answer (score 0):

Would doing:

```
var t2 = db.tests.Where(x => x.NullableInt == nullableInt ?? null).ToList();
```

Work?

It seems like utter madness though.

Comment: Madness indeed, and no, it doesn't work.  I tried putting in the generated SQl, but it keeps failing - I'm guessing it's protecting against some sort of injection attack